# Background div to resize height according to the contained elements

Tags: css, css-float

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I just can't get it to work:

this is "working" but only in a limited scenario (an example):

```
<div class="containerBK"></div> <!-- the background container--> 
<div class="somepagecontainer">
    <div class="userDetails">
        <div>some component</div>
        <div>another</div>
        <div>more</div>
        <div> some div that may or may not exist and with it's height varying</div>
    </div> <!--end user div-->
    <div class="left_column"></div>
    <div class="right_column"></div>
</div> <!--end of somepagecontainer-->
```

CSS:

```css
.containerBK {    
    width: 99%;
    height: 435px;
    background-image: url('../img/texture.png');
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    height:400px; /* hard coding the height! the problem */
}

.somepagecontainer {
    width:1024px /*setting the page text width*/

} 

.userDetails {
   overflow:hidden /*EDIT: So it would have a height, contains only floats*/
}
```

this gives me a nice full page width background for the upper part of the page (under the userDetails). The problem is that userDetails varies in height, and changes dynamically, so I need the background to resize accordingly.   but if I move `containarBK` into the main container the width becomes 99% of the 1024px container and I get both sides empty..

I'll be glad for help with this!

**EDIT:** I added a clarification about .userDetails class
**Update:** The missing part was changing the `overflow hidden` to `:after{clear:all, content:''}`

Comment: can you please provide fiddle if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the background-div inside of the userDetails-Div.

Then you have to give "position: relative" to the userDetails Div. Give the background-image div position: absolute; and position it to cover from top to bottom of the parent div.

To get the background-div to reach accross the left and right side of the userDetails-Div, you  have to give it margin-left: -9999px; and margin-right: -9999px; (arbitrary but high numbers).

However you will have to give "overflow-x: hidden" to the body element because otherwise you would see scrollbars with this solution.

Working example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="userDetails">
        <div class="background-image"></div>
        <div>some component</div>
        <div>another</div>
        <div>more</div>
        <div> some div that may or may not exist and with it's height varying</div>
    </div> 

    <div>Other content here</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.background-image {
    background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/wild_flowers.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: -9999px;
    margin-right: -9999px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.userDetails {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V66HW/1/

Comment: Thanks @francesco this is almost working.. seems that the fact that .userDetails is having an overflow:hidden. breaks this solution. I need the overflow hidden so userdetails (which is only a container to various floats) would have a height. any solution to that?

Comment: In how far do you need the overflow: hidden on .userDetails? You can just give .userDetails a height, or add an element with clear: both; at the end of .userDetails.

Comment: I don't want to set a height.. so I added the clear:both and accepted the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you should set up the background on the main container if you want it to resize accordingly. `<div class="containerBK"></div> <!-- the background container-->` is above the container that will resize depending on the content, so it will never adjust.

Comment: But I need the background to be a full page width while the main container is just the view width (1024 in my case)